# Convert written out date (DD.MMMM.YYYY at hh:mm apm) string into date value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Unfortunately, the Google-Sheets sync extension saves the timestamp as a string. (Example: February 6, 2022 at 11:40 pm). Is there any way of automatically converting this automatically to an actual date? I tried the usual date conversion formulas but they dont work. Maybe a work-around?

Comment: In what range are the strings running? A2:A? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a timestamp is in cell A2, try this:

```
=1*SUBSTITUTE(A2,"at","")
```

This just gets rid of the word "at" and then multiplying by 1 forces an attempt to convert it into a date value.  Then you can just do a regular Format>Number>Date and Time on that cell and it should show how you'd want.

Comment: That works perfectly! I kinda helped myself with an extra column taking the first part of the date (left & find) and then converting that to a date but yours is much more smooth and efficient! Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your string-dates are in A2:A.

Place the following formula into the Row-2 cell of any other open column (e.g., B2):

`=IF(A2:A="",,DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"^(.+),\s"))+REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\d+:.+$"))`